# How would i go about automatic name generation

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics

For my project I am required to go through a file and every car I find I have to name it using 3 letters and 2 numbers. Ex: ABC01. how would i program a function to automatically generate names like these, for example it starts with AAA01 and goes all the way to AAA99, then it goes to AAB01 and so on until I run out of cars to name. My question is simply how do i make a function produce these names, the if statement I can create to check if there are any cars left to name. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is good for this:

```
from itertools import product
import string

pools = [string.ascii_uppercase]*3 + [string.digits]*2
names = (''.join(c) for c in product(*pools) if c[-2:] != ('0', '0'))
# next(names) will give you the next unused name
```

For example:

```
>>> next(names)
'AAA01'
>>> next(names)
'AAA02'
>>> next(names)
'AAA03'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.product`...

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import product

def my_key_generator():
    letters = product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3)
    letters_nums = product(letters, range(1, 100))
    for letters, nums in letters_nums:
        yield '{}{:02}'.format(''.join(letters), nums)
```

And then to check:

```
from itertools import islice
keys = my_key_generator()
print list(islice(keys, 101))
# ['AAA01', 'AAA02', 'AAA03' [...snip...] 'AAA98', 'AAA99', 'AAB01', 'AAB02']
```

Comment: This is really cool, I started to learn python this year so my knowledge of modules etc is currently limited, glad to know its fairly easy to do and less complicated then the way i wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.3+

```
import string
from itertools import product

L = string.letters[26:]
I = map(str, range(10))
names = map("".join, itertools.product(L, L, L, I, I))
```

Usage:

```
>>> for n in names:
>>>     print n
```

Or

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> print(list(islice(names, 0, 10)))
['AAA00', 'AAA01', 'AAA02', 'AAA03', 'AAA04', 'AAA05', 'AAA06', 'AAA07', 'AAA08', 'AAA09']
```

For Python 2.7+ you should use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`.